# Entity Framework seems to be changing the real name of poco object

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a Database (sql server ) table name :   `InternInterest`

Then in my code I have nothing but the word  `InternInterest`  , whether is is as a property, part of repository or unit of work,  but yet somehow after ninject spins up and the project runs it throw this error:

`{"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:\r\n\r\nInterestIntern: Name: The EntitySet 'InterestIntern' with schema 'dbo' and table 'InternInterest' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table.\r\n"}`

`One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:`

`InterestIntern: Name: The EntitySet 'InterestIntern' with schema 'dbo' and table 'InternInterest' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table.`

There simply is NO such thing as `InterestIntern` in my project,  how could this happen?

So in the controller (web api )  it is hitting this

```
[Route("api/assignment/GetAssignments")]
public List<Assignment> GetAssignments()
{
   var result = _UnitOfWork.AssignmentsRepository.Get();
   return result;
}
```

Of which GenericRepository Get method

```
 public virtual List<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = _DbSet;

        foreach (Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> include in includes)
            query = query.Include(include);

        if (filter != null)
            query = query.Where(filter);

        if (orderBy != null)
            query = orderBy(query);

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

I am seeing

```
    `Message    "The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe."    string`
```

refresh:

"Exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' was thrown."}

Well now I seem to be getting this error

'System.TypeInitializationException

Additional information: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.

Still on that `return query.ToList();`

Comment: What does your DbContext look like?

Comment: Lot of   public virtual IDBSet<entityname> entitynames {get;set;}

Comment: lot of modelbuilders too      protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<AcademicLevel>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Interns)
                .WithOptional(e => e.AcademicLevel)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.CurrentAcademicLevel);